# Forms authentication in asp.net mvc 3 - ActionResult Register method - how to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

can you please help me. I have written logon and logout methods correctly using forms authentication in asp.net mvc 3.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(Guest guest, String returnURL, bool RememberMe = false)
{
    var isValidURL = bl.IsValidReturnUrl(returnURL);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The username or password provider is incorrect");
        return View(guest);
    }

    if (bl.IsUserValidated(guest.Username, guest.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(guest.Username, RememberMe);
        if (isValidURL)
            return Redirect(returnURL);
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");
    }
    return View(guest);
}
```

How to write a **Register** controller method, I don't know where to start, I have my own database in which I should insert new registered users with their username, password and email. Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking... Do you want guidance or do you want a sample? Or do you want somebody to write this for you?

Comment: Create a brand new MVC application selecting the "Internet Application" template. It contains all those methods and you can copy from there.

Answer (score 0):

In general you get their registration details (at the very least username and password, but best also email) and send it back to the register action.

Check that the username and password match your criteria. Then, check for duplicate users. If there aren't, you register to the database and inform them that they are registered.

You should really register their account as inactive at first, and send them an email with an activation link. When they access the link, have your action set the account to active and inform them that now they can use the website.

Does that help?

Comment: You have a binary field in your database, called say "Active", which you set to true or false depending on whether the "Activate" action has been passed the correct value or not.